# Request allowing short answers/comments

Tags: feature-request

In some rare cases a short answer or comment is appropriate, so I suggest allowing them. In those cases I have had to do stupid things like **My answer.............** or simply repeating **Answer Answer Answer**  or **Comment comment comment** to reach the character minimum. It seems kind of idiotic to force the contributor to put junk into their answer to meet some kind of arbitrary minimum.

An alternative approach would be just to issue a warning "Your answer seems unusually short" or something.

Answer (score 8):

You are asking for a SE software change, which isn't something most readers here can implement. Probably a better place to ask would be https://meta.stackexchange.com/

That being said, I seriously doubt you'll find a very receptive audience there. That limit is put in for a reason. It filters out a lot (and I do mean a lot) of trivial answers that really ought to be comments, or not even said at all.

In my 6.5+ years of active SE participation, I think I've chaffed at it once. Pretty much any answer you can make which is that curt will be improved with an extra sentence or two explaining yourself.